# Whats the disadvantage of setting a too high batch size?

Tags: sql, spring, postgresql

I set the `batch_size` in application.yml:

```
spring:
  profiles: dev
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        generate_statistics: true
        jdbc:
          batch_size: 20
```

Whats the reason that `batch_size` should not be set to a value as high as possible? Whats the disadvantage of setting `batch_size` to lets say 10000? Doesn´t it behave the same as `batch_size: 20` for <= 20 queries and for > 20 queries it keeps sending them in one batch instead of doing another request to the database. Isn´t that a better behaviour than setting it to a lower value like 20?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for small batch sizes is the memory consumption.

From the docs:

> Hibernate caches all the newly inserted Customer instances in the
>   session-level cache, so, when the transaction ends, 100 000 entities
>   are managed by the persistence context. If the maximum memory
>   allocated to the JVM is rather low, this example could fail with an
>   OutOfMemoryException. The Java 1.8 JVM allocated either 1/4 of
>   available RAM or 1Gb, which can easily accommodate 100 000 objects on
>   the heap.
>
> long-running transactions can deplete a connection pool so other
>   transactions don’t get a chance to proceed.
>
> JDBC batching is not enabled by default, so every insert statement
>   requires a database roundtrip. To enable JDBC batching, set the
>   hibernate.jdbc.batch_size property to an integer between 10 and 50.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#batch-session-batch